# Right CTRL not working in Lubuntu LXTerminal (but Left Ctrl does)

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, nano, lxterminal

New Linux User. Tried nano in Lubuntu 17.10 LXTerminal. <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> commands do not work. <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> commands do. I am running in Oracle VirtualBox.

Why?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is surely <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> whether coming from the left one or the right? Never this problem in Windows.

Thank you

Comment: If you try running windows inside Oracle Virtual Box it won't see the press of the right-ctrl either.  Oracle-Virtual-Box uses the right-ctrl for its own purposes and doesn't pass it to your guest-OS.  Your complaint is with VirtualBox, and not your guest-OS Lubuntu.  (Oracle have said they won't fix this so use a different editor, or a different vm)

Comment: does the right CTRL key work outside of `nano` as expected?

Comment: @Dan It does, of course. This is as simple as the first comment says. Virtualbox uses Right CTRL for toggling modes so it must "hijack" the key. This has nothing to do with the guest OS or the host, it's a Virtualbox feature that they already said won't be changed so...

Comment: thank you all. i understand now. sorry about such noob question.